# Mysql comments information display

Tags: mysql, comments, display

question about comments display, the example as below:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `foo`;
delimiter //
-- comment1
-- comment2
-- comment3
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS int(1)
BEGIN   
SET @var1 = @var1 + 1;   /* information here */
RETURN @var1;   
END;
//
delimiter ;

show create function foo;
```

the result of function foo did not contain any comments, is there anyway to show the comments out for development purpose only?

Comment: Keep reference scripts in some form of external .sql files for future development purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you include the comments within the function body.

If you are using the mysql cli on a *nix platform you could grep out the comments out by setting the PAGER and then use either SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE dbname.procedure_name or query the information_schema routines table. Don't forget to reset the PAGER afterwards.

e.g.

```
mysql> pager grep '\-\-'
PAGER set to 'grep '\-\-''

mysql> select routine_definition from information_schema.routines where routine_name = 'myaes_convert'\G
  DECLARE gtg TINYINT DEFAULT 0;     -- OK to proceed
  DECLARE vtable_schema VARCHAR(64); -- cursor var
  DECLARE vtable_name VARCHAR(64);   -- cursor var 
    -- Perform Backups on columns
    -- Perform Index backup
    -- Drop indexes
    -- Call column converter
    -- Create triggers on table
    -- Restore indexes and log
    -- rename the table _myaes
    -- create the view for this table
  SELECT 1; -- Phew!
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> pager
Default pager wasn't set, using stdout.
```

or

```
mysql> pager grep '\-\-'
PAGER set to 'grep '\-\-''

mysql> show create procedure myaes.myaes_convert\G
  DECLARE gtg TINYINT DEFAULT 0;     -- OK to proceed
  DECLARE vtable_schema VARCHAR(64); -- cursor var
  DECLARE vtable_name VARCHAR(64);   -- cursor var 
    -- Perform Backups on columns
    -- Perform Index backup
    -- Drop indexes
    -- Call column converter
    -- Create triggers on table
    -- Restore indexes and log
    -- rename the table _myaes
    -- create the view for this table
  SELECT 1; -- Phew!
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> pager
Default pager wasn't set, using stdout.
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, issue still exist. This situation is strange, and I thought about the reason is relative that My account have no select the privilege of base table mysql.proc. But not sure , I try to execute many comment way in either command line or Navicat but still have no comment.

Comment: Only usage and all privileges on my database.

Comment: Well, that should be enough, if you can define a function you can certainly show it back. I gave examples of this method using one of the stored procedures on my system, I note you were defining a function. Did you, by any chance, use "show create procedure" and not "show create function" when you tested it?

Comment: Yes I know that in my past experience on MySQL DB.  But the result still “eat” our comments. We try to figure out the root cause by debug the process and feedback in here if we got it. Thanks again.

Comment: hi, Paul. we confirm that the our MySQL database proxy remove all comments via security reason for prevent SQL injection operation. So this issue being resolved. thanks for your help!!